# Is InstallShield LE in VS2012 a trial version

Tags: installshield

Is InstallShield LE in VS2012 a trial version?

If so, what is an alternative way to set up websites and services using VS2012?

If not, can I use this InstallShield LE setup for commercial purposes? That is, can I give this to our clients for setting up websites and applications?

Thanks,

Jayakumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really a trial version but a very very limited version of their product. You need to register/activate in order to use it but I believe you can use it to distribute commercial solutions; the appropriate information is in the Flexera web site when you register.

If you were on VS2013, you could look into using Microsoft's Visual Studio projects now that they (finally!) decided to bring it back: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx

They have the same functions as they did in VS2010 but, depending on your needs, you are likely to find it better than IS LE.